# How do you populate dynamic dropdowns based on a number field in database?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to implement a drop down that will have numbers 1 - *value in database*.

I can get as far as displaying the value from the database in the dropdown, but can't get the numbers from 1 onwards to be created as options in the dropdown.

Below is my asp code:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource
    ID="selectSprintLength"
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:scConnection %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM sc_sprints WHERE scSprintID = @sprint">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="sprint" Name="sprint" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="sprintLengthDropDown"
    runat="server"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="sprintDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged"
    DataSourceID="selectSprintLength"
    DataTextField="scSprintTotal"
    DataValueField="scSprintTotal"
    AutoPostBack="true"
    EnableViewState="true" />
```

And this is my c# code:

```
protected void sprintDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int x = Int32.Parse(sprintLengthDropDown.SelectedValue);
    do
    {
         counter++;
    }
    while (counter < x);
}
```

Can anyone please help so that values 1 - scSprintTotal are all options in the dropdown. For instance scSprintTotal is 7, the drop down values would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the dropdown with series value we can use Enumerable.Range(starting_number, range); Please see the tutorial https://www.dotnetperls.com/enumerable-range

```
sprintLengthDropDown.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 7);
sprintLengthDropDown.DataBind();
```

You can make the range dynamic as the value from database.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct answer as well as useful. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
 int items;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from scSprint",con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            Label1.Text = "The total is " + dr["scsprinttotal"].ToString(); 
            items = Convert.ToInt32(dr["scsprinttotal"].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
        for (int i = 1; i <= items;i++ )
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

    }
```